# Javascript const matchMedia code not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a responsive drop down menu for my website so I decided I wanted to use javascript to make the situation easier. But for some reason I can't even get this simple js code to work, the color of my text is not changing to red. I'm not sure what I've done wrong, but any help/suggestions are very appreciated.

[image: Color of text is not red!]

```js
const mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");

if (mq.matches){
    document.body.style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: This will work if the browser window is smaller than 500px. You can easily test this by using a larger value. The text will appear red. So, if that's not what you actually want to achieve,  provide more information please.

Comment: Well when I do rezise my window in the inspect tool the color is still not changing to red.

Comment: The code you have is only executed once. If you want to execute it when the dimensions of the window change then you have to setup the appropriate event handlers. But changing CSS values based on media queries is much easier done in a CSS file. Then you don't have to setup event listeners.